# CloseHandle of windows thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, threadpool

This is a fundamental question. I am working on win32 threads and C++. How does Closehandle work here in the below code? In each iteration, are 5 threads created? or only 5 threads created for whole program and reutilized in each iteration? If not, how to call threadpool? Here tasks are just getting an element from the queue for each thread and do operation on those elements.

```
thread_fun(..) {
//synchronize to get one element for each thread
}
main() {
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    //Fill queue with 10000 elements and pass this to thread function
         for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
             _beginthreadex(..);
         WaitForMultipleObjects(..);
     }
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
         CloseHandle(..);
}
```

Please enlighten me.

Comment: No, it creates 5 threads for each iteration.  Calling CloseHandle() seems a bit pointless, the code as posted is leaking thread handles badly.  Using a threadpool is an unhappy match with 5 threads, it won't work well with a cpu that has 4 cores.

Comment: I don't want to create 5 threads in each iteration. How to achieve the same result without creating threads in each iteration?

Comment: Hard to help you.  Where does the number 5 come from?  Is it just a random guess at an optimum number or is it related to the algorithm?

Comment: I will change it to 8 as i am running this on a quad-core processor which supports 8 threads. Then how can i implement?

Comment: Hint: Every time `_beginthreadex` is called, a new thread is born.

Comment: I understood.. but how to reutilize the created thread?

Comment: When you create a thread it begins executing the code you provide. If you want to roll your own thread pool system then the code you provide will need some mechanism of communication so your main thread can tell it what to do. The implementation of this is really up to you.

Comment: Then what is the use of CloseHandle() function?

Comment: That releases the handle to the thread and frees up some resources, but the thread itself may still be running.

Comment: @JonathanPotter does it mean that we call the CloseHandle just after creating the thread ? please answer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465681/when-to-call-closehandle