# When to call CloseHandle?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a Main thread that receives actions that take some time. So i create a thread and delegate the job to it. This execute function is being called by the main thread when it receives jobs. each job implement this execute.

```
Return_type execute( Arguments_here) {

// if a file read case
DWORD threadId;
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread( 
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // use default stack size  
        MyAsyncFileRead,       // thread function name
        details,          // argument to thread function 
        0,                      // use default creation flags 
        &threadId);   // returns the thread identifier
// else do other work
}
```

Now since i do not want to wait on the main thread, i do not call WaitForSingleObject. [ my knowledge of windows thread is low. so if this is not required, pardon me ]

If i wait for the thread to close, it would wait my main thread. I do not want to do that.
So when do i call CloseHandle ?

When one has got like 10 jobs in hand and one creates 10 threads and then wait for all 10 threads to finish, then it looks good to wait_for_multiple_objects and then call CloseHandle on each handle.

But what should i do in this case ?

[ I suppose that this question would be relevant for all OS so tagging them too. ]

Comment: Don't worry about it and use `<thread>` :)

Comment: Clearly you've given all the reasons to immediately calling CloseHandle(hThread).  After checking that you actually managed to get it started of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really do not care about waiting for the thread, you can indeed close the handle immediately after creating the thread.

However, I strongly advise against doing that. You should **always** wait for threads to exit (preferrably in a clean, well-defined way). If not done earlier, wait for every thread you spawned when the program exits. Always, no exceptions.
Do not leave `main` not knowing whether or not some other threads are still running. If need be, kill them the hard way (though preferrably, let them exit gracefully in a controlled manner, and wait for it).

If you *don't* wait for threads to finish, you may see weird crash-on-exit conditions. Or worse, you might *not* see them, and only have users/customers complain that one in a hundred times the config file gets corrupted (or worse, a data file of theirs)<sup>1</sup>. Now imagine that they are able to demonstrate step-by-step what they're doing, and you can tell that they do everything correctly, and there is no way something could go wrong.
Good luck figuring out that the crash is due to a still-running worker thread accessing some object (or global state) which was just deallocated by the exiting main thread, either explicitly or implicitly by the CRT.

Of course your stance could be that the worker thread will have exited long before the program finishes anyway, so why bother. However, that is playing Russian Roulette.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is not fiction, but something I've actually seen happen before.

Comment: Thanks for the great insight. Does moving to std::thread would solve this problem. ?

Comment: Using std:thread makes your code portable but does not solve this or any other race condition. You must still make sure that only valid objects (or memory) are accessed at all times, including at program exit. Joining all threads ensures that things don't go wrong unexpectedly at exit.

Comment: Is there something like threadpool that i can instantiate globally and then delegate this thread to it. And if my program is ending, then i would just do threadpool.close() which would block untill all threads end. ?

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't have a readily available threadpool, but this is relatively straightforward to implement (see for example [this](http://progsch.net/wordpress/?p=81)). Under Windows (Vista+) you can even use the built-in threadpool. Or, you can implement your threadpool using IOCP (which is what I did long before Vista, very straightforward). It's not all that hard. The only thing you have to make sure in either implementation is that you signal and join (or, if you must, kill) in the threadpool's destructor, so you are 100% sure that no threads _that you don't know about_ stay alive.

Comment: would not killing threads would cause the same problem of data corruption ?

Comment: Possibly, that is why I keep saying "if you must" and "preferrably exit gracefully". Though killing worker threads is still likely to cause less havoc than freeing global resources and letting the threads crash. Preferrably, workers run in a loop where they pull 1 task at a time from a threadsafe queue, and if that task is a "null task", they exit. Alternatively they could regularly check a boolean. If no such thing is applicable, killing them at program exit is still better than letting them crash, presumed that you're not interested in the results any more.

Comment: Adding to my above comment a year and half later in order to make it somewhat more precise: Using `std::thread` you can either detach or not detach a thread (detaching means you have the same situation as with a Win32 thread, not detaching means you must `join()` it). Not detaching a thread also means that the destructor will call `std::terminate` when the thread object goes out of scope if you failed to call `join()`. This is equally undesirable, since `std::terminate` kills the process without calling global destructors, without running atexit handlers, and without flushing file buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `unique_ptr<HANDLE, CloseHandle> threadHandle` - assuming you have a suitable place for the `threadHandle` variable to be stored/placed..

Or, if you don't actually need the handle, just close it immediately after starting the thread, as the handle is only really useful if you care about the thread later on.

From MSDN [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs:

> The thread object remains in the system until the thread has
>   terminated and all handles to it have been closed through a call to
>   CloseHandle.

If at some later stage you need a handle to the thread, you can always use [`OpenThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a "new" handle. Assuming of course you didn't "lose" the `threadId` as well.

Of course, the correct C++ solution is to use `std::thread`.

Comment: i do not need the handle :)